# How to make Excel file with Selected Items on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I'm trying to save Log file as Excel.

I have **EventInfo.cs** file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class EventLogInfo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }     
    public string Camera { get; set; } 
    public string Device { get; set; }
    public Int16 Region { get; set; }
    public Int16 Event { get; set; }
```

There are Id, Camera, Device, Region, Event Items.

I use [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084) KB article and I can make it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ExcelOutput  

public partial class ExcelOutput : Window
    {
        public ExcelOutput()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          try
            {
                //Start Excel and get Application object.
                //oXL = new Excel.Application();
                //oXL.Visible = false;
                //oXL.UserControl = false;
                //oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;

                oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Id";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Camera";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Device";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Region";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Event";
```

When I click Excel output button, Excel files are created. But I want to select some items (Id, Camera, Device, Region, Event) and save as Excel.

What is the best way to select items and how make Excel files selected items sorted?

Answer (score 0):

As you've already created your Excel file, you just have to place your data in corresponding cells;

```
if (InitializeExcel())
{
dynamic cell;
cell = oSheet.Cells[1, 1]; cell.Value = Id;
cell = oSheet.Cells[1, 2]; cell.Value = Camera;
.
.
.
}
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the Open XML SDK. This way you can create Excel files without the need to have Excel installed. It's also faster.